# Taskbar and launcher not appearing

Tags: launcher, taskbar

The taskbar and unity launcher is not appearing when I sign in, however I do not have this problem on any other account. If anyone could help me solve this issue I would be grateful. I am running ubuntu 14.04LTS

Thanks
-T.Martin